# RegEx to find json values without quotes

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I'm having an issue with a parser (in this case PowerBI) not taking values that are not quoted.

The example JSON file which comes from an API is validating ok, but PowerBI is not having any of it:

```
{'requester_id': 361114274894, 'submitter_id': 361114274894, 'assignee_id': 361282665913, 'organization_id': 360009532534, 'group_id': 360000498954, 'name':'John Doe'}
```

I'd like to find all values without quotes so I can replace them.

Please help.

Comment: That's not JSON, it's JavaScript. You need to `JSON.stringify` it before writing the file.

Comment: It's the output I got from an API. It's not the full output of course, it's a subset, but the unquoted values are giving me an issue.

Comment: Its just digits, match digits and replace them surrounded by quotes?

Comment: If the api is outputting single quoted property keys that is invalid JSON. If the property keys are double quoted and numbers are not quoted that is perfectly valid. Beyond that you haven't provided a proper problem description and this sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: PowerBI is not accepting it as it is, so I have to put them in quotes.

Comment: I've also edited the post for clarity.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness replacing just digits will not work, as there are digits that are in quotes.

Comment: Match them with [\b\d+(?=,|$)](https://regex101.com/r/MpPxMM/2) ?

Comment: Why *would* Power BI accept it? Again, *it's not JSON*. The problem is the API is not returning valid JSON, it's just returning JavaScript. String mangling is **not** a good fix, either fix the upstream API or explicitly stringify it to valid JSON in your layer. Use the built-in functionality, which will handle all of the edge cases for you.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you'd like to convert your int values to string.

```
var json = {'requester_id': 361114274894, 'submitter_id': 361114274894, 'assignee_id': 361282665913, 'organization_id': 360009532534, 'group_id': 360000498954, 'name':'John Doe'}

    Object.keys(json).forEach(i => json[i]=json[i].toString());

    // output
    json
    {
      assignee_id:"361282665913"
      group_id:"360000498954"
      name:"John Doe"
      organization_id:"360009532534"
      requester_id:"361114274894"
      submitter_id:"361114274894"
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the for in loop. Assuming all non string items are numbers the following will work.

```js
const obj = {
  a: 123,
  b: "234234",
  c: 09,
};

console.log(obj);

for (key in obj) {
  obj[key] = obj[key] + "";
}

console.log(obj);
```

If the goal is to gather all the keys with non-string values rather than replacing them you can save them to an array and manipulate them later:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 123,
  b: "234234",
  c: 09,
};
const arr = [];

for (key in obj) {
  if (typeof obj[key] !== "string") {
    arr.push(key);
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with the use of single quotes instead of double quotes around the property names.

```
let correctedInput = input.replace(/'/g, '"');
let parsedInput = JSON.parse(correctedInput);
```

`parsedInput` will now be your javascript object.

`input.replace(/'/g, '"')` will find and replace all `'` characters, and replace them with `"` characters. This should work fine unless any of your property values have single quotes in them - For example, the name `O'malley` will be parsed incorrectly.

Answer (score -2):

You can perform the regex pattern matching as below in Java

String rtype="^\"|\"$";

String value = ((JSONObject) nameOfObject).get("key").toString().matches(rtype);

or

((JSONObject) nameOfObject).get("key").toString().replaceAll(rtype);

Comment: he is not talking about Java but JavaScript. They are two complete different things.